# Binary to Decimal in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pascal

I'm trying to do a simple console program where user input a binary string and he get a decimal number. I dont need to check if the binary string have something else than 0 or 1. I already managed to do decimal to binary but can't do it the other way.

I tried some code found on SO and Reddit but most of the time i got error I/O 105

Here's the dec to bin :

````pascal
program dectobin;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Crt32;

var
 d,a :Integer;
 str :String;

begin
   str:='';
   Readln(a);
   while a>0 do begin
    d:=a mod 2;
    str:=concat(IntToStr(d),str);
    a:=a div 2;
  end;
  Writeln(str);
  Readln;
end.```
````

Comment: I/O error has nothing to do with converting between binary and decimal. I/O error is related to I/O. So is your question about the I/O, or about the conversion. An important lesson to learn is to break your code into smaller pieces which perform single tasks. Write a function to convert a binary string into an integer value. If you can't make it work, show it here and ask for help. But as it stands this question simply asks us to write the code for you. That's not what SO is about, and it actually won't help you at all.

Comment: And by the way, you are not converting between binary and decimal. The value held in an `Integer` is actually represented by the machine in binary. You are converting between a string containing a binary representation of a number, and the number.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan
More about how to do it, and yes sorry if it was not clear, i'm definitly talking about a string containing a binary to a decimal (or a string containing that decimal)

Comment: No. You are not converting binary to decimal, or vice versa. The way to think about this is that an `Integer` variable holds the value, and your `string` variables hold representations of that value, decimal or binary or hexadecimal or whatever. Internally the `Integer` actually represents the value as binary but that's a detail that you almost never need to know.

Comment: As for your question, my advice in the initial comment stands. Remove all the I/O from the code, write a function that attempts to convert from a binary representation held in a string, to an `Integer` value. If you get stuck, come back with that code. The code you present here performs the reverse operation and so is completely unrelated to the problem you are asking about. At the sake of repeating myself, we aren't here to write the code for you. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour]. These steps are vital in order for you to get the most out of SO.

Comment: You are saying that you're having trouble with a program that converts binary to decimal.  You say that you were successful writing a program that converts decimal to binary.  You show us the program that was successful.  You need to show us the program that's giving you trouble.  Where's the source code for the decimal-to-binary program that's giving you the I/O error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basics of positional number systems (PNS)

- The number of unique digits in a PNS is its base (or radix)

  - The decimal system (base = 10) has ten digits, 0..9
  - The binary system (base = 2) has two digits, 0..1
- The position of a digit in a number determines its weight:

  - the rightmost digit has a weight of units (1), (base)^0 (decimal 1, binary 1)
  - the second (from right) digit has a weight of (base)^1 (decimal 10, binary 2)
  - the third (from right) digit has a weight of (base)^2 (decimal 100, binary 4)
  - and so on ....

Note that the weight is always `base * weight of previous digit` (in a right to left direction)

General interpretation of a string of numbers in any positional number system

```
  assign a variable 'result' = 0
  assign a variable 'weight' = 1 (for (base)^0 )
  repeat
    read the rightmost (not yet read) digit from string
    convert digit from character to integer
    multiply it by weight and add to variable 'result'
    multiply weight by base in prep. for next digit
  until no more digits
```

After previous, you can use e.g. `IntToStr()` to convert to decimal string.